# Raspberry Pi Fask Server: Cannot find images in folder using AJAX AND broken id search

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, date, raspberry-pi

First time using Raspberry Pi, linux, and server stuff, so please try to explain on a 101 level

I am trying to make a screen thing that is usually found in lobbies to show corporate slides, and the weather. I was able to get the weather working just fine, as it is a basic drop in. The main issue I have is I am trying to make updating the images as easy as "Throw images in folder, refresh page".

I made this originally using the basic python server setup, which automatically uses the file tree of the location, but when I copied it over to raspberry pi python with flask, it no longer acknowledges the folder. the items are there, but the folder does not work

The other issue I have is that the day field never gets established before the startTime() function executes, resulting in a null reference to 'day'. I already surrounded the function with window.onload, but that did not even make it work

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you. I know I posted a lot of code below, I put a comment beside the busted parts

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
 return """
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Made June 10th, 2020 by Collin Barker, 97Cweb -->
    <!-- Must be run on server opened to index location. Use command prompt to get to file folder containing index. Then start up python server -->
    <!-- python -m http.server -->
    <!-- https://weatherwidget.io/ -->
    <!-- dateTime from https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>


    <style>
        .scroll-div {
          height:150px;
          overflow-y: scroll;
        }
        .carousel-item-next, .carousel-item-prev, .carousel-item.active {
          display:block;
        }
        .carousel{
          margin-top:25px;
        }

        .weatherwidget-io{
          margin-top:25px;
        }
        .clock-container{
          display:flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
        }

        .daytime { 
          background-color:#87ceeb; 
          color:black;
        }
        .sunrise { 
          background-color:#ffca7c; 
          color:black;
        }
        .night { 
          background-color:#223344; 
          color:white;
        }
        #day{
          font-size: 5em;
        }
        .logo{
          margin-top:3.5%;
        }

    </style>    

    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Page stuff goes here -->


        <main class="col-12 " role="main">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="clock-container">
                        <!--
                        <div id="day"></div>       <!--affected box for broken date -->
                        <div id="month-year"></div>
                        -->
                        <div id="clock"></div>
                    </div>

                    <a class="weatherwidget-io" href="https://forecast7.com/en/42d31n83d04/windsor/" data-label_1="WINDSOR" data-label_2="WEATHER" data-days="3" data-theme="original" >WINDSOR WEATHER</a>
                    <script>
                    !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src='https://weatherwidget.io/js/widget.min.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,'script','weatherwidget-io-js');
                    </script>
                    <style>.embed-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%; } .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }</style>

                    <div class='embed-container'>
                        <!-- https://surfing-waves.com/feed.htm -->
                        <!-- start sw-rss-feed code -->
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        <!--
                        rssfeed_url = new Array();
                        rssfeed_url[0]="https://rss.cbc.ca/lineup/canada-windsor.xml"; rssfeed_url[1]="https://rss.cbc.ca/lineup/topstories.xml";  
                        rssfeed_frame_width="350";
                        rssfeed_frame_height="260";
                        rssfeed_scroll="on";
                        rssfeed_scroll_step="6";
                        rssfeed_scroll_bar="off";
                        rssfeed_target="_blank";
                        rssfeed_font_size="12";
                        rssfeed_font_face="";
                        rssfeed_border="on";
                        rssfeed_css_url="https://feed.surfing-waves.com/css/style7.css";
                        rssfeed_title="on";
                        rssfeed_title_name="";
                        rssfeed_title_bgcolor="#3366ff";
                        rssfeed_title_color="#fff";
                        rssfeed_title_bgimage="";
                        rssfeed_footer="off";
                        rssfeed_footer_name="rss feed";
                        rssfeed_footer_bgcolor="#fff";
                        rssfeed_footer_color="#333";
                        rssfeed_footer_bgimage="";
                        rssfeed_item_title_length="100";
                        rssfeed_item_title_color="#666";
                        rssfeed_item_bgcolor="#fff";
                        rssfeed_item_bgimage="";
                        rssfeed_item_border_bottom="on";
                        rssfeed_item_source_icon="off";
                        rssfeed_item_date="off";
                        rssfeed_item_description="on";
                        rssfeed_item_description_length="175";
                        rssfeed_item_description_color="#666";
                        rssfeed_item_description_link_color="#333";
                        rssfeed_item_description_tag="off";
                        rssfeed_no_items="0";
                        rssfeed_cache = "a6be76d5cf7fb849474d6758a6f37935";
                        //-->
                        </script>
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="//feed.surfing-waves.com/js/rss-feed.js"></script>
                        <!-- The link below helps keep this service FREE, and helps other people find the SW widget. Please be cool and keep it! Thanks. -->
                        <div style="color:#ccc;font-size:10px; text-align:right; width:230px;">powered by <a href="https://surfing-waves.com" rel="noopener" target="_blank" style="color:#ccc;">Surfing Waves</a></div>
                        <!-- end sw-rss-feed code -->

                    </div>


                    <img class="logo d-block w-100" src="/static/logo.png" >
                </div>

                <div class="col-9">
                    <div class "carousel-holder">
                        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <div class="carousel-inner" id="slide-container">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="h1">Welcome to Comfort Inn South Windsor</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main> 

    <!-- End of page stuff -->



    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var folder = "static/slides/";
            var href=window.location.href;
            var pathArray=href.split('/');
            var path="";
            var activated=false;
            for(i=0;i<pathArray.length-1;i++){
                path+=pathArray[i];
                path+="/";
            };
            path+=folder;
            console.log(path);

            $.ajax({ <!-- stuff breaks here, path does not exist according to execution in chrome-->
                url : path,
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {


                    **$(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
                        if( val.match(/\.(jpg|jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
                            var output="<div class=\\"carousel-item";
                            if(!activated){
                                output+=" active";
                                activated=true;
                            }
                            output+="\\"> <img class=\\"d-block w-100\\" src=\\""+ path + val +"\\"></div>";
                            console.log(output);
                            $("#slide-container").append( output );**
                        } 
                    });
                }
            });

        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function startTime() {
      var today = new Date();
      var y = today.getFullYear();
      var mo = today.getMonth();
      var d = today.getDate();
      var h = today.getHours();
      var m = today.getMinutes();
      var s = today.getSeconds();
      mo=checkTime(mo+1);
      m = checkTime(m);
      s = checkTime(s);
      document.getElementById('day').innerHTML = d;        <!-- broken line that throws null exception-->
      document.getElementById('month-year').innerHTML =  mo + "/" + y;
      document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML =  h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
      var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);

      <!-- Background color changing -->
      <!-- https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/kdDBL -->
      h=s;
      if (h > 19 || h <= 6){
      // If time is after 7PM or before 6AM, apply night theme to ‘body’
        document.body.className = "night";
      }
      else if (h > 6 && h < 9){
      // If time is between 6AM – 9AM sunrise theme to ‘body’
        document.body.className = "sunrise";
      }
      else{
      // Else use ‘day’ theme
        document.body.className = "daytime";
      }
    }
    function checkTime(i) {
      if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
      return i;
    }
    </script>


  </body>
</html>


"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```

old code that worked with python -m http.server

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Made June 10th, 2020 by Collin Barker, 97Cweb -->
    <!-- Must be run on server opened to index location. Use command prompt to get to file folder containing index. Then start up python server -->
    <!-- python -m http.server -->
    <!-- https://weatherwidget.io/ -->
    <!-- dateTime from https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var folder = "slides/";
            var href=window.location.href;
            var pathArray=href.split('/');
            var path="";
            var activated=false;
            for(i=0;i<pathArray.length-1;i++){
                path+=pathArray[i];
                path+="/";
            };
            path+=folder;
            console.log(path);

            $.ajax({
                url : path,
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {


                    $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
                        if( val.match(/\.(jpg|jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
                            var output="<div class=\"carousel-item";
                            if(!activated){
                                output+=" active";
                                activated=true;
                            }
                            output+="\"> <img class=\"d-block w-100\" src=\""+ path + val +"\"></div>";
                            console.log(output);
                            $("#slide-container").append( output );
                        } 
                    });
                }
            });

        });
    </script>

    <script>
    function startTime() {
      var today = new Date();
      var y = today.getFullYear();
      var mo = today.getMonth();
      var d = today.getDate();
      var h = today.getHours();
      var m = today.getMinutes();
      var s = today.getSeconds();
      mo=checkTime(mo+1);
      m = checkTime(m);
      s = checkTime(s);
      document.getElementById('day').innerHTML = d;
      document.getElementById('month-year').innerHTML =  mo + "/" + y;
      document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML =  h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
      var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);

      <!-- Background color changing -->
      <!-- https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/kdDBL -->
      h=s;
      if (h > 19 || h <= 6){
      // If time is after 7PM or before 6AM, apply night theme to ‘body’
        document.body.className = "night";
      }
      else if (h > 6 && h < 9){
      // If time is between 6AM – 9AM sunrise theme to ‘body’
        document.body.className = "sunrise";
      }
      else{
      // Else use ‘day’ theme
        document.body.className = "daytime";
      }
    }
    function checkTime(i) {
      if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
      return i;
    }
    </script>


    <style>
        .scroll-div {
          height:150px;
          overflow-y: scroll;
        }
        .carousel-item-next, .carousel-item-prev, .carousel-item.active {
          display:block;
        }
        .carousel{
          margin-top:25px;
        }

        .weatherwidget-io{
          margin-top:25px;
        }
        .clock-container{
          display:flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
        }

        .daytime { 
          background-color:#87ceeb; 
          color:black;
        }
        .sunrise { 
          background-color:#ffca7c; 
          color:black;
        }
        .night { 
          background-color:#223344; 
          color:white;
        }
        #day{
          font-size: 5em;
        }
        .logo{
          margin-top:3.5%;
        }

    </style>    

    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body  onload="startTime()">
    <!-- Page stuff goes here -->


        <main class="col-12 " role="main">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="clock-container">
                        <!--
                        <div id="day"></div>
                        <div id="month-year"></div>
                        -->
                        <div id="clock"></div>
                    </div>

                    <a class="weatherwidget-io" href="https://forecast7.com/en/42d31n83d04/windsor/" data-label_1="WINDSOR" data-label_2="WEATHER" data-days="3" data-theme="original" >WINDSOR WEATHER</a>
                    <script>
                    !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src='https://weatherwidget.io/js/widget.min.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,'script','weatherwidget-io-js');
                    </script>
                    <style>.embed-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%; } .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }</style>

                    <div class='embed-container'>
                        <!-- https://surfing-waves.com/feed.htm -->
                        <!-- start sw-rss-feed code -->
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        <!--
                        rssfeed_url = new Array();
                        rssfeed_url[0]="https://rss.cbc.ca/lineup/canada-windsor.xml"; rssfeed_url[1]="https://rss.cbc.ca/lineup/topstories.xml";  
                        rssfeed_frame_width="350";
                        rssfeed_frame_height="260";
                        rssfeed_scroll="on";
                        rssfeed_scroll_step="6";
                        rssfeed_scroll_bar="off";
                        rssfeed_target="_blank";
                        rssfeed_font_size="12";
                        rssfeed_font_face="";
                        rssfeed_border="on";
                        rssfeed_css_url="https://feed.surfing-waves.com/css/style7.css";
                        rssfeed_title="on";
                        rssfeed_title_name="";
                        rssfeed_title_bgcolor="#3366ff";
                        rssfeed_title_color="#fff";
                        rssfeed_title_bgimage="";
                        rssfeed_footer="off";
                        rssfeed_footer_name="rss feed";
                        rssfeed_footer_bgcolor="#fff";
                        rssfeed_footer_color="#333";
                        rssfeed_footer_bgimage="";
                        rssfeed_item_title_length="100";
                        rssfeed_item_title_color="#666";
                        rssfeed_item_bgcolor="#fff";
                        rssfeed_item_bgimage="";
                        rssfeed_item_border_bottom="on";
                        rssfeed_item_source_icon="off";
                        rssfeed_item_date="off";
                        rssfeed_item_description="on";
                        rssfeed_item_description_length="175";
                        rssfeed_item_description_color="#666";
                        rssfeed_item_description_link_color="#333";
                        rssfeed_item_description_tag="off";
                        rssfeed_no_items="0";
                        rssfeed_cache = "a6be76d5cf7fb849474d6758a6f37935";
                        //-->
                        </script>
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="//feed.surfing-waves.com/js/rss-feed.js"></script>
                        <!-- The link below helps keep this service FREE, and helps other people find the SW widget. Please be cool and keep it! Thanks. -->
                        <div style="color:#ccc;font-size:10px; text-align:right; width:230px;">powered by <a href="https://surfing-waves.com" rel="noopener" target="_blank" style="color:#ccc;">Surfing Waves</a></div>
                        <!-- end sw-rss-feed code -->

                    </div>


                    <img class="logo d-block w-100" src="logo.png" >
                </div>

                <div class="col-9">
                    <div class "carousel-holder">
                        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <div class="carousel-inner" id="slide-container">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="h1">Welcome to Comfort Inn South Windsor</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main> 

    <!-- End of page stuff -->



    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: NOT A TECHNICAL ANSWER

I was able to work around it and get the original code working again. My Pi was running python 2.7, so getting the right command to turn on the python test server fixed the old one